# Raspberry Pi with ESC and PS3 Controller

Tags: python, playstation3

I am new to coding and I am trying to control ESCs through a PS3 controller which will be coded on the Raspberry Pi B+. I think this can be done, but i have read in a lot of places that I need to use an additional board? Is this the case?

I have found some code which i was going to manipulate..

http://www.raspians.com/Knowledgebase/ps3-dualshock-controller-inst...

http://mechnable.com/content/raspberry-pi-controlling-4-servos-via-...

Please advise me on if I need another board?
My project: is to create a system which can VTOL. So I wanted to control the ESCs with an input from the PS3 controller.

Comment: This does not really directly look like a general programming question; if you need advice about Raspberry PI beyond programming, you can try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you, I have posted in that forum :D